# What does "Chitagnikunda Sambootha" mean in Sri Lalita Sahasranama?

Tags: lalita, translation

The very first invocation para of Sri Lalitha Sahasranama begins with the title words "Chitagni kunda".
It appears to me that "chit-agni-kunda sambhootha" represents the "spark of thought or imagination". So essentially it starts off with the prelude that this whole Sahasranama of Sri Lalitha is the "spark of the imagination" of a poet describing Sri Lalitha.

Answer (score 1):

"chit-agni-kunda sambhootha" does not represent the "spark of thought or imagination", but "one who was born from the altar of the ***fire of consciousness***"

[Bhaskararaya](https://archive.org/details/LalitaSahasranamaWithBhaskarRaiCommentary1925AnantaSastry/page/n61) in his commentary says on this name, as follows;

> Chit, pure Brahman, and he is the altar of fire; for  he dispels the
> darkness of ignorance (Avidya).
>
> In the stanza, "In the fire of consciousness that burns within uninterruptedly, without fuel,
> dispelling the darkness of illusion" we see that consciousness is
> compared with fire.  The commentary in the Sakti Sutras on the Sutra
> beginning "chitvahni... " (the fire of consciousness, etc.) says
> "consciousness is fire because by its nature it consumes the
> Universe." Born (Sambhuta):  By the quality called consciousness she
> abides in that fire, but is not born from it.  Because consciousness
> and the thing possessed of that is one and the same.